# How do you bind the return value of an Object method to the DOM in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

Let me make the problem a bit more specific - I can bind the return value when in an ngFor:

```
<select id="addTimeslotSelect" style="height:24px; background-color:rgb(235, 235, 228);"  disabled>
  <option *ngFor="let day of days" data-value="{{day}}" data-label="{{day.toDateString()}}"></option>
</select>
```

day.toDateString() works fine. However when I want to access a particular index outside of an ngFor I cannot seem to get it to work.

```
<input id="addTimeslotTextbox" data-value="{{days[days.length-1].toLocaleDateString()}}" type="text" disabled/>
```

days[days.length-1].toLocaleDateString() does not work here. I get the following error: "Cannot read property 'toLocaleDateString' of undefined"

Curious if anyone has insight as to why it works in the former case and not the latter.

Comment: try using an elvis operator .? `{{days[days.length-1]?.toLocaleDateString()}}`. Probably when the view is initialised days array is undefined

Comment: I've been looking at providing a default as well to display something other than a blank if resolving takes some time or never happens, like "..." or something, I think this works (I'm still a little new to the "safe navigation" operator):

{{myObj?.value || '...' }}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since on initial Change detection `days` array have not intialize. So you should use `Navigation operator`(`Elvis operator`) here.

```
data-value="{{days[days.length-1]?.toLocaleDateString()}}"
```